Apache Beam Python SDK, WriteToJdbc and Batch Size
I created a pipeline which reads from BigQuery and writes to MSSQL with Jdbc. It tooks too much time to write the data to MSSQL because batch size is 1000 by default. I didn't manage to change it.
How to change batch size to WriteToJdbc in Python?
My WriteToJdbc code:
| "Write" >> WriteToJdbc(
                                table_name=jdbc_table,
                                driver_class_name=jdbc_driver_class,
                                jdbc_url=jdbc_url,
                                username=jdbc_user,
                                password=jdbc_password,
                                connection_properties="",
                                max_connections=-1,
                            )

Example pipeline that reads and writes 10.000.000 rows:


Seems like this is not supported currently. I created https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/32891 for tracking.

Thank you @chamikara, I will be watching this issue.
